# rust referencing and ownership

Tags: rust

I watch many tutorials and courses about rust referencing and ownership but I still having errors with it.
i have a stricture and I have a function I called it `__init__()` ( I call it every time when I initialize the class) (and I am a python developer)

```rust
impl Draggable2 {
    pub(crate) fn __init__(mut self) {
        self.drag_handler();
        self.drag_over_handler();
    }
}
```

```rs
 self.drag_over_handler();
   |         ^^^^ value used here after move
```

---

- I got a similar error when I use a clouser two time
- here I am using rust with web_sys.

```rs
impl Draggable2 {
    pub(crate) fn drag_handler( mut  self) {
        let my_closure = Closure::wrap(Box::new(move |event: web_sys::MouseEvent| {
            log_1(&format!("{:#?}", self.doc).into());
        }) as Box<dyn FnMut(_)>);

... other code ...
.
.
.

}
```

### error

```rs
or[E0382]: use of partially moved value: `self`
  --> src/editor/plugins/draggable_2/drag_handler.rs:19:46
   |
15 |         let my_closure = Closure::wrap(Box::new(move |event: web_sys::MouseEvent| {
   |                                                 --------------------------------- value partially moved into closure here
16 |             log_1(&format!("{:#?}", self.doc).into());
   |                                     -------- variable partially moved due to use in closure
...
19 |         let closure = Closure::wrap(Box::new(move |event: web_sys::MouseEvent| {
   |                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ value used here after partial move
...
22 |             let mut curr = self.get_curr(&event);
   |                            ---- use occurs due to use in closure
   |
   = note: partial move occurs because `self.doc` has type `web_sys::Document`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if you think that your main issue is an ownership issue, you're completely wrong. **Rust is not OOP¹, you can't (mustn't) use classes and above all you can't simply apply Python knowledge into Rust as-is** (in particular, calling a function `__init__`...). Trying to make classes in Rust is an anti-pattern, meaning you will only ever have trouble trying to use it. Before everything else (in particular, before learning about references and ownership) you have to learn about common patterns in Rust. I would suggest reading [Rust by Examples](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/).

Once this is out of the way, you will probably understand why this code is wrong: if you have an associated method, such as `drag_handler`, that takes `mut self`, then it takes the ownership of `self`. To understand, you have to desugar what a method call actually is: your `__init__` method is actually

```rust
impl Draggable2 {
  fn __init__(mut self) {
    Self::drag_handler(self); // <-- Here, ownership is given to `Self::drag_handler`
                              // <-- Here, `self` is no longer valid because
                              //     it was given away
    Self::drag_over_handler(self);
  }
}
```

In this version, it's quite clear that you are passing ownership of `self` to a function, then trying to use `self` again, which makes the compiler complains. What you probably meant was to use `&mut self` instead, which just takes a mutable borrow, and not the ownership, to `self`, giving:

```rust
impl Draggable2 {
  fn __init__(&mut self) {
    self.drag_handler();
    self.drag_over_handler();
  }
  fn drag_handler(&mut self) {
    ...
  }
  fn drag_over_handler(&mut self) {
    ...
  }
}
```

To understand better, I would strongly recommend reading at least once (if not twice) the Rust book, which is a very good tutorial for beginners, short (for the amount of information contained), to the point, and with references to other books for more details, if wanted (notably to the Rustnomicon).

---

<sup>¹This is not exactly [what the Rust Book says](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-01-what-is-oo.html). However, the Rust book is extremely vague about what being OOP means, and the fact is whether Rust is OOP or not, most OOP patterns are not applicable in Rust and sometimes lead to severe anti-patterns, among which the [inheritance simulation with `Deref`](https://github.com/rust-unofficial/patterns/blob/main/anti_patterns/deref.md). What is also clear is that Python relies **much more** on OOP patterns that Rust, so if you come from Python it's simply clearer to formulate it this way: Rust is **not** OOP in the sense that a lot of what you do in Python would be done in an other way in Rust. A good example is the usage of "[magic methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-lookup)", ie. methods in Python which start with `__`, or which start and end with `__`. `__init__` is a good example of such magic method. They exist to solve a specific issue that does not exist in Rust, due to the language design, therefore using magic methods in Rust makes no sense.</sup>

Comment: I thought that would be solved by using `#[derive(Clone, Copy)]` to my struct? However, I am not sure how to implement this yet because it requires to to to change the arguments of the class to implement copy `Error: the trait `Copy` may not be implemented for this type` and ` pub doc: Document,----this field does not implement `Copy`

Comment: Also, it is really good idea to compina the Rust-book [with those videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLai5B987bZ9CoVR-QEIN9foz4QCJ0H2Y8)

Comment: @alial-karaawi there are situations in which you *want* to move the data around, and also you want to keep it where it is, that is, you want to duplicate data implicitly. For instance, it is the case for numbers, as it's very cheap to duplicate numbers. In this case, `#[derive(Clone, Copy)]` is the appropriate solution. However, this is not the case here. You should really use `&mut ...` instead.